# VBA: Rename sheet to previous month, year

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to rename a sheet to the previous month, year - "MMM yyyy"
For example, using today's date, I'd want the sheet to be renamed to "JUN 2021"

I have the following code but this keeps outputting "Jan 1905". This also does not account for cases where today's month would be January 2022. The output using this code would be "Dec 2022"

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = Format(Month(Date) - 1, "MMM") & Format(Year(Date), "YYYY")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EoMonth`. You also need to upper-case the formatted output: `MMM` doesn't actually upper-case the month.

```
Dim lastMonth As Date
lastMonth = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)

Sheets("Sheet1").Name = UCase$(Format$(lastMonth, "Mmm Yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = Format(DateValue(Month(Date) - 1 & "/1/2021"), "mmm yyyy")
```